# How to rename existing table in the data base using Kotlin Exposed framework?

Tags: ddl, kotlin-exposed

I can't find any information on how to rename an existing table in a database using Kotlin Exposed framework? If possible, please give me any explanation. Thank you in advance.

I read all official documentation but not found any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use execute statement function like this.

```
transaction {
    exec("alter table [old_table_name] rename to [new_table_name]")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that

```
private fun rename() = transaction {
    db.connector().prepareStatement("alter table [old_table_name] rename to [new_table_name]", false)
}
```